# Unsatisfied dependency for com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

In order to remove the `PLAY INSTALL REFERRER API` permission from my app, I've removed the `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2` dependency from *Gradle*, but at runtime, I get this error log:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay]>{2, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessaging, type=required, direct=true}]}: interface com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6693)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6594)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay]>{2, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessaging, type=required, direct=true}]}: interface com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.validateDependencies(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:170)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.processInstanceComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:89)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:73)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:418)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:300)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1921)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1896)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6693) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6594) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

In my app I use firebase services for only the following reasons:

- Push notification to the users
- Write and read data from Firebase database
- Display App message dialog (*Inappmessaging-Display*)

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'cn.ezandroid:EZFilter:2.0.9'
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.alexvasilkov:gesture-views:2.5.2'
    implementation('com.github.christophesmet:android_maskable_layout:v1.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.intellij', module: 'annotations'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.duanhong169:checkerboarddrawable:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.AKiniyalocts:imgur-api:-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'

    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'com.github.nanchen2251:CompressHelper:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.waynejo:androidndkgif:0.3.3'
    implementation 'com.yanzhenjie:mediascanner:1.0.3'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.takwolf.android:aspectratio:0.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

I tried adding this to the `app/build.gradle`it worked for me.

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
> ```

[Btw it's part of Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
```

Answer (score -1):

Unpacking apk found less configuration：
add config worked for me.

```
<service android:directBootAware="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
```